What does security mean in "strikes not only at security" in this context?
The word security has at least 5 different meanings according to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary and Thesaurus, the author is talking about financial issues like deflation and inflation so I do not think he is talking about some sort of guarantee, neither do I think he is talking about bond or stock certificates as if it were the case, he would have used "securities" instead of security, so I guess he is actually talking about the safety of something though I am not sure what safety he is referring to. This is the text fragment:

By a continuing process of inflation, governments can confiscate, secretly and unobserved, an important part of the wealth of their citizens. By this method, they not only confiscate, but they confiscate arbitrarily; and, while the process impoverishes many, it actually enriches some. The sight of this arbitrary rearrangement of riches strikes not only at security, but at confidence in the equity of the existing distribution of wealth.

Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 99). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
Likewise, in the case of equity, he is not talking about a house's equity but about the justness of the wealth distribution.

Have you looked up "strike" in a good dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strike

@JavaLatte I do understand the meaning of "strike for this context" What I wanted to know was the meaning he is using for the word security in that phrase.

I. Expanding the phrase:
OP has asked the meaning of the phrase "strikes not only at security" in:

"The sight of this arbitrary rearrangement of riches strikes not only at security, but at confidence in the equity of the existing distribution of wealth.”

In this sentence, "strikes" is the main verb governing two objects:

"security"
"confidence in the equity of the existing distribution of wealth"

The phrase means that seeing or becoming aware of the unfair redistribution of wealth harms both people's sense of financial security and their confidence in the fairness of wealth distribution.
The phrase "of wealth" is a prepositional phrase modifying both "security" and "distribution."

"Security of wealth" refers to the stability and safety of wealth.
"Distribution of wealth" refers to how wealth is shared or allocated within society.

II. Dictionary meaning of "security" and "equity":

1. Security (FREEDOM FROM RISK).
The definition "freedom from risk and the threat of change for the worse" (e.g., financial/job security) fits best in this context. The passage discusses how inflation can erode wealth, leading to insecurity about financial stability. The "security" here refers to the financial protection or stability from the loss of wealth.
2.  Equity  (FAIRNESS).
The definition "fairness" is the most appropriate here.
"The equity of the existing distribution of wealth," meaning how fairly wealth is shared among the population. The passage implies that the arbitrary redistribution of wealth weakens people's confidence in the fairness of the system.

III. Explaining the paragraph:
Over time, inflation allows governments to quietly reduce people's wealth.
This happens in an unfair and unpredictable way, where many lose wealth, while some benefit.
This unfair shift in how wealth is spread threatens people’s financial security and undermines their trust in the fairness of how wealth is distributed in society.

The possession of savings affords a certain degree of security -- protection from harm -- in that you can use it handle some disasters.  If the government's actions causes the value of your savings to diminish, they have struck at the security thus provided.

The value of the money itself is being eroded. That value is insecure. But since that value is measured by what people can do with money they have, its purchasing power, the security of people comes into play: security in respect to whatever the proverbial "rainy day" might bring them, and security in their old age, when they are no longer able to earn money by working but must rely upon their savings ( what they've put aside voluntarily and as required by law, where applicable) and their investments, and perhaps upon family.
